Double model creation after payment in django website
I am currently working on Learning management course using Django and React .I am creating payment gateway using stripe . After the payment is successfully done , the courses should be called enrolled courses and a model of it created after payment . But for some issue , double course model gets created after payment for each course purchased. I don't know the issue in code.
I have attached the code of payment and model created .enter image description here
enter image description here
enter image description here
I tried to pay using stripe and get the enrolled course created of that course. But duplicate (double) enrolled course created for some reason.
This is the drive link for all the client side code snippets
https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/11UZcU7zNWKqq2tavR35K3weFzu6xaRRi?usp=sharing

The culprit might be how you are making the requests. If you are making them in effects that run on component mount and you are in <StrictMode>,  then that is definitely the culprit.

I have added the code snippet for payment , can you decode the error?

I can’t see the snippet you added. I said the issue must be a client side one not server side. Add the code that runs on the client and I will show you where the problem lies.

Can you share actual code snippets rather than images of code? Show snippets of when you call the methods to create these entities and the context in which those execute. Update: also not a drive link. You need to do the work to extract relevant snippets from your code.

That said, you have two create calls inside a for i in order_items loop. Should those run for each item is there are multiple? Only you can know this for your model.

https://codeshare.io/J7lQOr        This is the both side code for my wesbite

@NolanH Yes , if there is 2 order items in cart , for each item one notification model and enrolled course should be created . Then how can it will duplicate in both model

You'll need to add diagnostic logging to understand. Is PaymentSuccessAPIView the view that handles the redirect from Stripe Checkout after payment? You should track requests to this and determine if/why there might be two, and handle the creation idempotently.
